# Is u'string' the same as 'string'.decode('XXX')

Tags: python, unicode, decode

Although the title is a question, the short answer is apparently no. I've tried in the shell. The real question is why?
ps: string is some non-ascii characters like Chinese and XXX is the current encoding of string

```
>>> u'中文' == '中文'.decode('gbk')
False
//The first one is u'\xd6\xd0\xce\xc4' while the second one u'\u4e2d\u6587'
```

The example is above. I am using windows chinese simplyfied. The default encoding is gbk, so is the python shell. And I got the two unicode object unequal.

**UPDATES**

```
a = '中文'.decode('gbk')
>>> a
u'\u4e2d\u6587'
>>> print a
中文

>>> b = u'中文'
>>> print b
ÖÐÎÄ
```

Comment: When claiming the two are different, it would be useful to provide a concrete example.

Comment: You'll need to show us a good example of why you think that your question statement is not true. Perhaps your understanding of what your console encoding is differs from what really happens, for example.

Comment: Right, now you are assuming that your terminal is using `gbk` as the codec. That is not correct. You are not using the correct encoding here.

Comment: I **very much doubt** that the first one is `u'\xd6\xd0\xce\xc4'`. That would be GBK-encoded text decoded as Latin1.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Actually I think the terminal is using `gbk` as the codec. But why the first one is Latin1.

Comment: You pasted `gbk` bytes into the terminal, but Python thinks the terminal is configured as Latin-1. Which cannot be true, because then the `print` statement would fail.

Comment: What does `import sys; print sys.stdin.encoding, sys.stdout.encoding` print?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Not really, I typed the characters..

Comment: @MartijnPieters `cp936 cp936` similar to `gbk` which is Compatible

Comment: @zoujyjs: right, so you are on Windows. You are indeed pasting `cp936` data then but somehow Python is decoding it as Latin-1 (or similar). This may be a Windows console problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, `str.decode()` usually returns a `unicode` string, if the codec successfully can decode the bytes. But the values only represent the same text if the **correct** codec is used.

Your sample text is not using the right codec; you have text that is GBK encoded, decoded as Latin1:

```
>>> print u'\u4e2d\u6587'
中文
>>> u'\u4e2d\u6587'.encode('gbk')
'\xd6\xd0\xce\xc4'
>>> u'\u4e2d\u6587'.encode('gbk').decode('latin1')
u'\xd6\xd0\xce\xc4'
```

The values are indeed not equal, because they are **not the same text**.

Again, it is important that you use the *right codec*; a different codec will result in very different results:

```
>>> print u'\u4e2d\u6587'.encode('gbk').decode('latin1')
ÖÐÎÄ
```

I encoded the sample text to Latin-1, not GBK or UTF-8. Decoding may have succeeded, but the resulting text is not readable.

Note also that pasting non-ASCII characters **only** work because the Python interpreter has *detected* my terminal codec correctly. I can paste text from my browser into my terminal, which then passes the text to Python as UTF-8-encoded data. Because Python has asked the terminal what codec was used, it was able to decode back again from the `u'....'` Unicode literal value. When printing the `encoded.decode('utf8')` `unicode` result, Python once more auto-encodes the data to fit my terminal encoding.

To see what codec Python detected, print `sys.stdin.encoding`:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.stdin.encoding
'UTF-8'
```

Similar decisions have to be made when dealing with different sources of text. Reading string literals from the source file, for example, requires that you either use ASCII only (and use escape codes for everything else), or provide Python with an explicit codec notation at the top of the file.

I urge you to read:

- [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) by Joel Spolsky
- The [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html)
- [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html) by Ned Batchelder

to gain a more complete understanding on how Unicode works, and how Python handles Unicode.

Comment: Martijn says yes, Paulo says no?

Comment: @alvas: because we interpret the question differently; Paulo takes `XXX` to mean 'any codec'.

Comment: py 3.0+ is utf8 by default, no?

Comment: If `XXX` is always the script's input codec then the answer is yes :)

Comment: @alvas: Only the source encoding. For file reads and writes (including the terminal) the locale and the terminal encoding are consulted instead.

Comment: @PauloBu: That's what the OP is effectively saying, in my interpretation. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters reading carefully it actually seems so. I was mislead by he suggesting _no_ in the first place.

Comment: Anyway, I got the point. `u'string'` is decode using the default codec while 'string'.decode('codec') speficy the exactly codec which is prefered. Problem?

Comment: @zoujyjs: in the windows console, that appears to be the best way to go about it, yes.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming Python2.7 by the title.

The answer is *no*. No because when you issue `string.decode(XXX)` you'll get a Unicode depending on the codec you pass as argument.

When you use `u'string'` the codec is inferred by the shell's current encoding, or if it's a file, you'll get `ascii` as default or whatever `# coding: utf-8` special comment you insert at the beginning of the script.

Just to clearify, if codec `XXX` is ensured to always be the same codec used for the script's input (either the shell or the file) then both approaches behave pretty much the same.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The question assumes that `decode` is called with the correct codec.

Comment: Paulo says no, Martijn says yes?

Comment: though the string `string` is pretty much the same decoded from most common encodings.

Comment: Well, if you put it that way now I'm a bit scared about my answer hehe ;)

Comment: I don't think we can assume the string was taken from the Python source code here; note that the OP did not provide any sample code. If the text is loaded from a website, the source code encoding has no influence on what codec should be used to decode the text to Unicode.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I was doing this in python shell. See my update, I've pasted some testing code.