# How to print Chinese characters stored in a file with charset 'iso-8859-1' in python

Tags: python, encoding, character-encoding

I am trying to print the contents of a file. 'file -bi filename' command gives 'text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1'.
File has strings like "ÏÂÔØ¡¢°²×°¡¢¸´ÖÆ¡¢·ÃÎÊ¡¢µ¥»÷¡°½ÓÊÜ¡±°´Å¥£¬»òÒÔÆäËû·½Ê½Ê¹ÓÃ³ÌÐò"... Which is actually representing chinese characters.
I tried these on python shell

```
string='ÏÂÔØ¡¢°²×°¡¢¸´ÖÆ¡¢·ÃÎÊ¡¢µ¥»÷¡°½ÓÊÜ¡±°´Å¥£¬»òÒÔÆäËû·½Ê½Ê¹ÓÃ³ÌÐò'
a= string.decode('iso-8859-1')
b=a.encode('utf-8')
print b
```

and

```
print( string.decode('iso-8859-1').encode('utf-8'))
```

and

```
source_encoding = "iso-8859-1"
string = string.encode(source_encoding)
string = unicode(string, 'utf-8')
```

But I am not able to see Chinese characters on screen, instead i saw 'Ã�Ã�Ã�Ã�Â¡Â¢Â°Â²Ã�Â°Â¡Â¢Â¸Â´Ã�Ã�Â¡Â¢Â·Ã�Ã�Ã�Â¡Â¢ÂµÂ¥Â»Ã·Â¡Â°Â½Ã�Ã�Ã�Â¡Â±Â°Â´Ã�Â¥Â£Â¬Â»Ã²Ã�Ã�Ã�Ã¤Ã�Ã»Â·Â½Ã�Â½Ã�Â¹Ã�Ã�Â³Ã�Ã�Ã²" 
I used an online tool http://www.mdbg.net/chindict/chindict.php and I selected Current encoding: iso-8859-1 and original encoding GB18030 and I saw result as 国际程序许可协议...

Can any one suggest me a way to display these strings  in Chinese language using python commands?
Thanks in advance

Comment: iso-8859-1 cannot ever encode Chinese; `file` guessed wrong.

Comment: Use `repr()` to show us the actual bytes; you have a Mochibake here.

Comment: What Python version is this?

Comment: Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_character_encoding for options.

Comment: Related / possible duplicate: [Is u'string' the same as 'string'.decode('XXX')](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20973745)

Comment: Another one: [Chinese Unicode issue?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23268480)

Comment: @user2357112 I am using Python2.7

Comment: @MartijnPieters As you said 'file' command might have guessed wrong. repr('ÏÂÔØ¡¢°²×°¡¢¸´ÖÆ¡¢·ÃÎÊ¡¢µ¥»÷¡°½ÓÊÜ¡±°´Å¥£¬»òÒÔÆäËû·½Ê½Ê¹ÓÃ³ÌÐò') is "'\\xc3\\x8f\\xc3\\x82\\xc3\\x94\\xc3\\x98\\xc2\\xa1\\xc2\\xa2\\xc2\\xb0\\xc2\\xb2\\xc3\...'". Your wikipedia link is informative. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the online tool suggests, `file` is probably wrong, since it only 'guesses' the encoding. Using `gb18030` as the encoding gives the correct result:

```
>>> s = 'ÏÂÔØ¡¢°²×°¡¢¸´ÖÆ¡¢·ÃÎÊ¡¢µ¥»÷¡°½ÓÊÜ¡±°´Å¥£¬»òÒÔÆäËû·½Ê½Ê¹ÓÃ³ÌÐò'
>>> print s.decode('gb18030')
下载、安装、复制、访问、单击“接受”按钮，或以其他方式使用程序
```

Comment: Or GBK, the extension to GK2312 and very common.

Comment: @JayanthKoushik and @MartijnPieters,  This is what i wanted. Yes `file` has guessed wrong. I have used s.decode('gb18030') and s.decode('gbk'), both gave me expected result. I was not knowing that `file` guesses rather than finding out. Thank you

Comment: I am using Python 2.7.3 but got unreadable output like this:  

    sss = 'ÏÂÔØ¡¢°²×°¡¢¸´ÖÆ¡¢·ÃÎÊ¡¢µ¥»÷¡°½ÓÊÜ¡±°´Å¥£¬»òÒÔÆäËû·½Ê½Ê¹ÓÃ³ÌÐò'          
    print sss.decode('gb18030')          
    脧脗脭脴隆垄掳虏脳掳隆垄赂麓脰脝隆垄路脙脦脢隆垄碌楼禄梅隆掳陆脫脢脺隆卤掳麓脜楼拢卢禄貌脪脭脝盲脣没路陆脢陆脢鹿脫脙鲁脤脨貌```